# Clone all packages from a yaml file?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For ROS2, you can clone all registered packages with a simple command:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/master/ros2.repos
vcs import ~/ros2_ws/src < ros2.repos
```

How can you do the same for the ROS 1 package listed in this yaml file:
https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/melodic/distribution.yaml

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310959/clone-all-packages-from-a-yaml-file?/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit:

just checked and apparently `rosinstall_generator` accepts an `ALL` argument that: "specif[ies] all release packages":

```
  pkgname               catkin package names, rosbuild stack names or variant
                        names. Use 'RPP' to specify all packages available in
                        the current environment. Use 'ALL' to specify all
                        release packages (only usable as a single argument).
```

Running the following command gets me a `.rosinstall` file with approx 500 KB of info on all released packages in ROS Kinetic:

```
rosinstall_generator --rosdistro=kinetic --deps --tar ALL > all.rosinstall
```

Note that this also includes information on their dependencies. Adding `--deps` is probably not needed, as they can only depend on other ROS packages or system dependencies, and all ROS packages are already in the selection, but it won't hurt.

Note: this gets you a `.rosinstall` file for all packages *at the currently released version* (ie: released as of when you invoke that command).

---

> For ROS2, you can clone all registered packages with a simple command: [..] How can you do the same for the ROS 1 package listed in this yaml file: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/melodic/distribution.yaml

I don't believe there is tooling that will "clone all registered packages" for you. Or at least, not directly with/from that particular `.yaml` file. The `ros2.repos` file does not contain the same sort of abstractions / information as the `distribution.yaml`.

The former is a plain listing of repositories that `vcs` can clone for you (using `git` or another vcs tool), while `distribution.yaml` contains all sorts of meta-data about packages and repositories.

[rosinstall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator) can use that information to generate a `.rosinstall` file for you that is (at least conceptually) the same as the `ros2.repos` file: `.rosinstall` files contain the same sort of information, but are typically consumed by `wstool` (`vcs` can also consume them).

As `distribution.yaml` is a plain `.yaml` file, you could consider creating a simple Python script that loads it and then uses the `release` dicts in it to clone a specific version of *all* packages registered for that distribution. I'm not aware of a tool that does this already, as it's not a typical use of `distribution.yaml`.

If you'd like to do things a little more structured, you could actually use [rosinstall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator) to generate `.rosinstall` files specifically for a set of packages (so including their (transitive) dependencies).

You may actually be able to get `rosinstall_generator` to generate a `.rosinstall` file for all packages in the `distribution.yaml` though, by using certain parameters. I haven't checked whether that is possible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-18**:
This is (somewhat) related to the work we're doing with the [rosinstall_generator_time_machine](https://github.com/rosin-project/rosinstall_generator_time_machine), but there we go back in time first and then generate `.rosinstall` files.